# Bittorrent : What does the response message "????ackeConnection ID missmatch." from tracker server mean?

Tags: bittorrent

Now that any document does not describe this error message, I am here to post this thread.
I'm currently implementing Bittorrent client from scratch in
C. I have a problem with communicating with tracker server. it
sends me the message '  ackeConnection ID missmatch.'. I have sent the
following message as request message for a list of peers.

> GET
>   udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce?info_hash=%f7%e5%fe%a5%ed%94%3a%d5%a2%fc%7d%20%a1%bc%b5e%b6%e3%c1%25&peer_id=M7-3-5--%eck%a8%2a%7f%e6%3ah%84%f2%9d%c5&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=1007089122&event=started&compact=1&numwant=50

But it gives me as response message.

```
????ackeConnection ID missmatch.?
```

What does this response message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by the fact that you try to send a GET request to an UDP tracker.

check out these links for further information

http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html

http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/udp_tracker_protocol.html

[Torrent related: tracker response on UDP protocol (Update #3 - working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184376/torrent-related-tracker-response-on-udp-protocol-update-3-working)